# Run .efi file on virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, efi

I'm learning baremetal and creating .efi file I can run at boot, like [this pong game](https://github.com/Openwide-Ingenierie/Pong-UEFI)

But rebooting after compilation, then selecting the right drive to boot, just to test the file, is a bit tedious. How can I run the .efi file on a virtual machine? (like virtualbox or qemu?)

Comment: A virtual machine uses host hardware, so there is not much likelihood that a VM will help you. (Posted from my virtual machine here).

Comment: To run a .EFI file in Virtual Machine, you need to first create a UEFI firmware based VM. Then run EFI shell (VMware bas built-in shell option but not greatly supported) and then attach a USB pen drive with .EFI file and invoke it from Shell prompt. Alternatively rename  .EFI as bootx64.efi (for 64 Bit UEFI) and place it at \EFI\Boot folder on pen drive and attach the pen drive to VM and boot thru it.